# Dataweave calculating on groupBy with items

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I want to calculate the totalprice of articles per articlegroup with Dataweave in Mulesoft.

I have a solution but it looks a little bit cumbersome, maybe there is a better solution to do a calculation like this in Dataweave ?

```
//input
var varinput1 = [
   { "artname": "appelmoes", "artgroup": "groenten", "price": 4.20 },
   { "artname": "rode kool", "artgroup": "groenten", "price": 3.20 },
   { "artname": "tarvo brood", "artgroup": "brood & banket", "price": 1.20 },
   { "artname": "krentebrood", "artgroup": "brood & banket", "price": 0.80 },
   { "artname": "vlaai", "artgroup": "brood & banket", "price": 20.40 },
   { "artname": "beckers frikandellen", "artgroup": "vries", "price": 10.40 },
   { "artname": "magnum ijs", "artgroup": "vries", "price": 4.40 },
]

output application/json 
---
varinput1 groupBy ((item, index) -> (item.artgroup)) pluck ((value, key, index) -> (key) : value) map {
    (TotalPriceGroenten: ($.groenten.price) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item + accumulator)) if($.groenten.price != null),
    (TotalPricebroodenBanket: ($."brood & banket".price) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item + accumulator)) if($."brood & banket".price != null),
    (TotalPriceVries: ($."vries".price) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item + accumulator)) if($.vries.price != null)
}

//ouput

[
  {
    "TotalPriceGroenten": 7.40
  },
  {
    "TotalPricebroodenBanket": 22.40
  },
  {
    "TotalPriceVries": 14.80
  }
]
```

The only thing I could think of to improve the code is to change the output header in:

```
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
```

Maybe there is a better solution ?
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable can be created to lookup the key for the total Prices for each group. By accessing the groupBy values directly, there is no need to do null check.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json 
var varinput1 = [
   { "artname": "appelmoes", "artgroup": "groenten", "price": 4.20 },
   { "artname": "rode kool", "artgroup": "groenten", "price": 3.20 },
   { "artname": "tarvo brood", "artgroup": "brood & banket", "price": 1.20 },
   { "artname": "krentebrood", "artgroup": "brood & banket", "price": 0.80 },
   { "artname": "vlaai", "artgroup": "brood & banket", "price": 20.40 },
   { "artname": "beckers frikandellen", "artgroup": "vries", "price": 10.40 },
   { "artname": "magnum ijs", "artgroup": "vries", "price": 4.40 },
]

var totalPriceKeys = {
    groenten: "TotalPriceGroenten",
    "brood & banket": "TotalPricebroodenBanket",
    vries: "TotalPriceVries"
}

var artsByGroup = varinput1 groupBy $.artgroup
---
keysOf(artsByGroup) map ((key) -> {
    (totalPriceKeys[key]): artsByGroup[key] sumBy $.price
})
```